# Flyback Current Sense Resistor

Tags: power-supply, flyback

Just want to make sure that I understand how the current sense resistor works in this circuit:

[image]

Basically, we want to monitor the current through the primary side of the transformer, so we know when to switch the MOSFET on and off.

Rcs creates a voltage based on the primary side current and the value of the resistor (V = IR), and the CS pin of the flyback controller measures that voltage.

We have to choose an exceptionally low value for Rcs because we need to be able to generate a high enough current through the primary winding to achieve the output voltage that we desire.

What I do not understand is why can't we just monitor the current directly? Why do we need Rcs at all?

Comment: Rcs has a low value because any current through it will generate power that's wasted as heat. The more power, the bigger the resistor power rating. Meanwhile: can you describe (or give examples of) the circuitry you'd use to monitor the current directly, without a resistor like Rcs?

Answer (score 4):

Rcs is exactly how you monitor the current directly. It gives a measurable voltage proportional to the current.

Of course you could replace Rcs with something like a current transformer but it would be more expensive and possibly not as reliable.